# What is Linux and why go for it?

Tags: linux

If some one (Windows User, non-techie) asks you, what is Linux and Why go for it? What would you answer?

Need a technical answer.

Comment: You're asking for a technical answer for a non-technical person?  Kind of contradictory isn't it?

Comment: lol, by a technical answer, I didn't mean, it's detailed intricacies, but a high level technical overview of Linux.

Comment: Well, my my nontechnical answer to a non-techie asking why to go for Linux would be: Don't

Comment: Have you tried Wikipedia?

Comment: @ceejayoz That was a joke right?

Comment: @zengr No, it wasn't. Wikipedia gives a perfectly good explanation of what Linux is and what its advantages and disadvantages are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux is a generic term for any distribution running on the Linux Kernel. There are many 'flavours' (distributions) such as [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/), [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) and [Debian](http://www.debian.org/). It is an free and open source alternative to [Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix).

It is used for servers and desktop PCs alike.

Generally, it is more complex than windows, but runs a 'similar' to Mac OSX (which runs on FreeBSD, essentially.)

If I was to explain WHY they should go for it, it would really depend on what they wanted to use their PC for. Also, Your OS is less of a consideration than the applications you install.

With that in mind, if they wanted it for run-of-the-mill use such as writing documents and surfing the web, I would point them to [OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/) and [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/)/[Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) then explain that with Linux, they can do practically everything they do on windows, without have to spend hundreds on software.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is an operating system, like Windows and Mac OS X. Linux is typically used for running servers, but techie users will use it as their main OS.