# what is the advantage of using Linux compared with Windows OS?

Tags: linux, windows

Hi what is the advantage of using Linux server compared with Windows .. except secure and open source answer.

Comment: Most of the reasons Linux is awesome are directly related to the "open source answer".

Comment: Should either be made CW or closed due to subjective material.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/8467/why-switch-to-linux http://superuser.com/questions/731/why-not-switch-to-linux http://superuser.com/questions/121038/what-is-linux-and-why-go-for-it-closed

Question, however IMO is Subjective & Argumentative, voted to close for the same reason

Answer (score 1):

- you're cool
- some stuff doesn't work on windows, I'm currently trying to find a C-- compiler for the windows platform, no luck.
- more powerful commandline, more control, more extensibility
- but since seven, window's powershell is better than bash
- GUILE, SCRIPING IN SCHEME BABY.

Comment: Powershell will never be as good as bash until all windows executables put themselves in the path.

Comment: @Brendan *and* will respect command line options, which will probably never happen...

Comment: You don't want all Windows apps on the path unless Windows has had some recent changes to its plumming. On several occasions I've had to remove stuff from the path because it was too long, and Windows couldn't cope. I still use XP though, so maybe things have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has mentioned it yet: **Package managers**.

On Windows, you find your software by searching around online, then every time they're updated, you run the installer again (and get asked about all of the configuration all over again).

Example: Installing Firefox

```
apt-get install firefox
```

Example: Updating all installed programs:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

The second one is two part because one updates the database and the other upgrades everything.

Answer (score 0):

The most important reason is NO VIRUSES (AFAIK).

Some other reasons are:

- There are so many different distributions to choose from (I personally use Ubuntu)
- They are Open Source (in other words, alot of people work on it at the same time)
- Its UNIX (nuff said.)
- More options for the UI

Answer (score 0):

Subjective answer for a subjective question.

Read: [In the beginning there was the command line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Beginning..._Was_the_Command_Line)

I think he nails it when comparing OSs with vehicles:

- Windows is a station wagon.
- BeOS is the Batmobile.
- Mac OS is a luxury European car.
- Linux is a free tank that can feel every pebble being crushed under the treads.

So to answer your question: Linux has an advantage over Windows because it is (essentially) a  powerhouse (tank). However (depending on the person), that can be seen as a disadvantage. So people will generally settle for the (knowable) station wagon.